# (Act, Goldime, Outlook) VS (Salesforce)

Tags: outlook

How can I convince a company using 
 *Act*
- *Goldmine*
- *Outlook*
to use Salesforce instead?

Does someone know what are their main weaknesses?

Andrea

Comment: While I like this question, I feel it's too open ended and/or opinion-based to receive a proper answer. I tried. A compelling argument requires knowledge of how they use whatever tool they use. Personally, I'd suggest they contact sales and just ask, get a personalized experience. After all, they might not even know they need to switch, but a call or chat is free.